# Join attribute name to table name in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, rdbms

I need to create a table that stores multiple values for an attribute as so:

```
Table Main
____________________________________________________
| Person      |       Hobbies      |TimeSpent(hrs) |
----------------------------------------------------
|   John      | gardening, guitar  |  2,4          |
|   Harry     |     programming    |  8            |
----------------------------------------------------
```

After looking online, the solution seems to be involving separate tables as so and joining them:

```
Table John
| Hobbies     | TimeSpent |
---------------------------
|   Gardening |    2      |
|   Guitar    |    4      |
---------------------------

Table Harry
| Hobbies     | TimeSpent |
---------------------------
|  Programming|    8      |
---------------------------
```

Two questions:

1. Is this the correct way to do it? The tables John and Harry are expected to be huge.
2. How do I automatically create a table for each person with the table name as their respective names and how do I find table "John" from person John in table main?

Comment: Do not store lists of things (like hobbies) in a delimited string.  SQL has this great data structure for storing lists; it is called a *table*.

Comment: That's why I said that after looking online the solution seems to lie in creating tables called John and Harry as storing lists is not an option.

Comment: 1. No 2. Don't. I suggest you read about "primary keys" and "foreign keys", and forget about whatever online tutorial suggested you that god-awful design.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following design may work for you.

[PERSON]

PERSON ID (PRIMARY KEY),
NAME

[HOBBY]

HOBBY ID (PRIMARY KEY),
HOBBY

[PERSON_HOBBY]

PERSON_ID (PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY to PERSON),
HOBBY_ID (PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY TO HOBBY),
TIME_SPENT

The following statement should work for the new design:

```
SELECT p.NAME, GROUP_CONCAT( h.HOBBY ORDER BY ph.HOBBY_ID ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS 'HOBBIES', 
GROUP_CONCAT( ph.TIME_SPENT ORDER BY ph.HOBBY_ID ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS 'HOURS SPENT' 
FROM PERSON_HOBBY ph
LEFT JOIN PERSON p ON p.PERSON_ID = ph.PERSON_ID
LEFT JOIN HOBBY h ON h.HOBBY_ID = ph.HOBBY_ID
GROUP BY ph.PERSON_ID;
```

Comment: Don't use single quotes for column aliases (just leads to future problems).  Also, `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary if the tables have the proper foreign key relationships (which they should have).

Comment: In addition to what @GordonLinoff said, if you want to have a list of persons, including persons *without* a hobby, you should select from `PERSON` (and in this case the `LEFT JOIN` is warranted).